# Conditionally render component views based on browser screen size

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have three different components representing different views for screen sizes. I want to render one of them based on the browser view width. I've managed to get this working using ternary operators, but it'll only work with two elements.

Can someone let me know how to accomplish this without having to use `display: hidden` on one of the elements?

Here is my code so far:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../../shared/components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Page from "../../shared/interface/Page/Page";

{/* elements */}
import DesktopView from "../../home/components/DesktopView/DesktopView";
import MobileView from "../../home/components/MobileView/MobileView";
import TabletView from "../../home/components/TabletView/TabletView";

function Home() {
  const [isDesktop, setDesktop] = useState(window.innerWidth > 650);
  const [isTablet, setTablet] = useState(window.innerWidth > 768);
  const [isMobile, setMobile] = useState(window.innerWidth > 640);

  const updateMedia = () => {
    setDesktop(window.innerWidth > 1024);
    setTablet(window.innerWidth > 768);
    setMobile(window.innerWidth > 640);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateMedia);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateMedia);
  });

  return (
    <Page>
      <Navbar />

      {/* Elements should go here */}
    </Page>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following Code instead of ternary

```
isDesktop && <DesktopView />
isTablet && <TabletView />
isMobile && <MobileView />
```

So if `isDesktop` is true then only `DesktopView` will render and similarly `isTablet` will control `TabletView` and `isMobile` will control `MobileView` rendering

Comment: That's exactly the answer I needed. Thank you very much